# Using AWS Cognito to Authorize a Client Application and Users

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Let me just start with I am extremely new to OAuth 2.0 and security is not exactly my strength. Because of this, if something in my question sounds strange or hints that I have no idea what I am talking about, that is precisely why.

Moving on, we have a need for users to have access to our system, hosted on AWS, both through a user interface that we will be building and also through our API directly. The challenge is: when it comes to our API users, I am unsure how authorization should be performed for them. All of our users are mandated to reset their passwords every 6 months for legal reasons, which means that I cannot register any of the applications that will be accessing our API as app clients because Cognito does not allow client secrets to be changed once generated.

I am also getting the feeling that OAuth seems much more heavily geared for granting access to a service on the behalf of someone else rather than being geared toward granting access to a known entity directly, but I could be wrong.

I have been told that we need our customers (both UI and API) to be able to submit a username and password and get a token. I understand that the implicit grant has many security flaws and should not be used, so I don't want to use that, but how can I keep the experience easy for our API users?

Cognito's hosted UI makes things easy enough for people who will be logging in manually to use our system, but most of our business is all automated and I am just stuck on how to proceed.

They don't want the login process to be any more complex than (username + password) = token. With that being the case, and me not being a security expert, I am not sure how I should proceed with Cognito. I know this question might illicit opinions, but I'm hoping it's specific enough of a problem to get some specific responses. I'm just at a loss and don't know what else to do. I've been researching this for 2 weeks non-stop and I'm just totally lost. Any help is seriously appreciated.

Thank you.